# Select Combobox items when selecting a group

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable, combobox

I have a combobox in my .xaml

```
    <ComboBox Name="Group" Margin="50,71,330,618" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

And a other combobox in my .xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="Sort" Margin="20,71,0,618"/>
```

When i'm selecting an item from my combobox like 'Liquid' I only want to see the items from Table **Sort** which have the GroupName **Liquid**.

My FK/PK are correct in the database, but i don't know how to put it in my WPF.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, C# in WPF

In my .cs file I have the following query so it will always show the items in the combobox

```
  public AddStock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bindcomboboxgroup();
    }

        private void bindcomboboxgroup()
    {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"local";
            string SelectQuery = "SELECT Name From [Group]";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Groep.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Name"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred:\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution seems to be enough for you:

I created two tables (Group table and Sort table) with the following values:

[image: Group table]

[image: Sort table]

Note: if you need to use Application.StartupPath, add the System.Windows.Forms reference.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection SQLConnect = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\LocalDB.mdf;");
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CMD = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from GroupTable", SQLConnect);
            SQLConnect.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader SDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            GroupComboBox.Items.Clear();
            while (SDR.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < SDR.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    GroupComboBox.Items.Add(SDR[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            SQLConnect.Close();
        }

        private void Group_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CMD;
            switch (GroupComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                case "Gas":
                    CMD = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select G from SortTable", SQLConnect);
                    break;
                case "Liquid":
                    CMD = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select L from SortTable", SQLConnect);
                    break;
                case "Plasma":
                    CMD = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select P from SortTable", SQLConnect);
                    break;
                default:
                    CMD = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select S from SortTable", SQLConnect);
                    break;
            }
            SQLConnect.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader SDR = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            SortComboBox.Items.Clear();
            while(SDR.Read())
            {
                SortComboBox.Items.Add(SDR[0].ToString());    
            }
            SQLConnect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Tested in:

Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework 4.5.2, WPF, SQL Server 12.0.6024.0

Thanks

Comment: Note: if this solution helps you, please mark as answer (don't forget to vote for me)

Comment: i'll do! I was not able to test it sooner. I'm working on it now.